# select long raw blob oracle 8,1 using sql or vb6 or vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oracle, select, vb6, long-integer

I have long raw data type column. want to select it. Display it on screen for example. Or save it to file using vb6 or vb.net. No luck for me all day. Have this code so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION longrawtochar(v_raw long raw) return varchar2
is
  rawlen number;
  hex varchar2(32767);
  rawparam varchar2(32767);
  i number;
begin
  hex := rawtohex(v_raw);
  rawlen := length(hex);
  i := 1;
  while i <= rawlen
  loop
    rawparam := rawparam||CHR(to_number((substrb(hex,i,2)),'xx'));
    i := i + 2;
  end loop;
  return rawparam;
end;
```

Bu when I select it get illegal use of long datatype.

Comment: Check this: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_select_long_table_column_sql.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [LONG RAW](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/datatypes.htm#CJAEGDEB) datatype, apart from being deprecated in newer versions of Oracle PL/SQL, is generally of much greater length than `VARCHAR2` which has a maximum length of 32767 bytes.  If you want to display the value of the field (which is, after all, binary data)   why not look at using VB.NET SQL classes to select the value, and then dump it into a compatible datatype, like a byte array, for display on screen or streaming into a file?

VB.NET would allow you to use things like the [OracleClient.OracleDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.aspx) and an [OracleCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (deprecated from .NET 4.0 onwards, but still available as of .NET 4.5) to run a query for your `LONG RAW` and retrieve the value into a byte array.  (Please note, this example code is from my brain compiler as I don't have an Oracle database to test against):

```
Dim output As Byte()
Using conn As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection(strConnectionString)
    Dim command As New OracleCommand("SELECT MyLongRaw FROM LongRawTable", conn)
    conn.Open()
    Dim reader As OracleDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

    If reader.Read() Then
        If reader.GetBytes(0, 0, output, 0, reader.GetBytes(0, 0, Nothing, 0, 0)) > 0 Then
        ..Do Something With The Byte Array..
        End If
    End If
End Using
```

From there it should be a simple matter of sending that into a memory or file stream to output it to a file or other stream-compatible destination.